# Facebook and Twitter API

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I  am developing an Android small application. It will just handle connecting to and managing one Facebook and Twitter account.

How this can be done on Android platform?

Can someone show me a resource which can help me?

Comment: And GIRLS too, I'm sure?

Answer (score 4):

For twitter I have learned that the Intent API exposed by Twidroid is not really nice. Instead there is a small very high level library for Twitter called [Twitter4J](http://yusuke.homeip.net/twitter4j/en/index.html) that I used to build an Android App. Posting to twitter is literary as easy as:

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter("username", "password");
Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Hello World");
```

easy, huh?

I was at one point planing to write an Android Wrapper for this library, that exports common functionality with Intents (like you can start a Service with a twitter.PUBLISH_MESSAGE intent or you can declare your app to receive Intent Broadcasts when new tweets are available for your account) but I did not find the time yet (and also maybe it will be at some point be done by the OpenIntents guys).

Have fun!

Comment: yeeaaaah, that 's very cool.
Am going to se the library and see how to include it.

Comment: Whirlwinm, I am not sure what you mean. The library works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the full featured Twitter4J you could try the following extremely simple solution excluding all the helper methods and wrapper classes but including the dialog for OAuth authorization: http://www.tinyappworks.com/api/twitter.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Facebook API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Main_Page) and [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/).

You can use the [`DefaultHTTPClient` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) in the Android SDK for making HTTP requests.

Comment: okay thank you,
am going to see DefaultHttpClient and how to use this api with it